# how to make pretty photo layout fixed size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, prettyphoto

I have a [prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) implementation in my site.And my problem is that according to the size of image prettyphoto layout always changes.I would like to make it a fixed size.
I have tried making the `href` of link to a specific size image.But it is not working.
The code as far as i tried

```
 <a class="zoom" id="zoom-image" height="290" width="267" href="/images/imagehandler.ashx?path=/product-images/334.jpg" >
    <img id="large-image" src="/images/imagehandler.ashx?path=/product-images/334.jpg&amp;width=267&amp;height=290">
  </a>
```

Comment: Just add **Height** & **width** attribute in img tag
`<img id="large-image" height="290" width="267" src="/images/imagehandler.ashx?path=/product-images/334.jpg&amp;width=267&amp;height=290"/>`

Comment: @dholakiyaankit It does not works :(

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prettyphoto.js script change the code

```
pp_dimensions = _fitToViewport(imgPreloader.width,imgPreloader.height);
```

to this code -

```
 pp_dimensions = _fitToViewport(800, 800);
```

Comment: This thing works but I want to make outer layout only static.This makes entire picture size also static.means images are fit to layout..that makes images to streatch

Answer (score 1):

Apply the @soheil solution :

pp_dimensions = _fitToViewport(700, 550);

This fixes the width but when you navigate through the slides it appears a awful animation on the right margin, it shrinks and expand 20px for a second.

The solution is to change the _showContent function, from :

```
$pp_pic_holder.animate({
            'top': projectedTop,
            'left': ((windowWidth/2) - (pp_dimensions['containerWidth']/2) < 0) ? 0 : (windowWidth/2) - (pp_dimensions['containerWidth']/2)
            ,width:pp_dimensions['containerWidth']
        },...
```

to

```
        $pp_pic_holder.css('width', pp_dimensions['containerWidth']);

        // Resize picture the holder
        $pp_pic_holder.animate({
            'top': projectedTop,
            'left': ((windowWidth/2) - (pp_dimensions['containerWidth']/2) < 0) ? 0 : (windowWidth/2) - (pp_dimensions['containerWidth']/2)
            /*,width:pp_dimensions['containerWidth']*/
```

This code deletes the animation on the right margin.

If you fix the width of the window you have also to manage the responsiveness. 
I also added these rules:

```
.pp_content {min-height: 400px;}
.pp_content_container .pp_details {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute!important;/*this positions the navigation bar in the same place on the bottom*/
    bottom: 10px;
}
    @media all and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:700px)
    {
        div.pp_pic_holder {width: 80%!important;}

        .pp_content {
            width: 100%!important;
            height: 70%!important;
        }

        #pp_full_res {zoom:0.8;}

        .pp_content_container .pp_details { 
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }

    @media all and (max-width:480px) 
    {
        div.pp_pic_holder {width: 80%!important;}

        .pp_content {
            width: 100%!important;
            height: 80%!important;
        }

        #pp_full_res {zoom:0.7;}

        .pp_content_container .pp_details { 
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<a class="zoom" id="zoom-image" href="/images/imagehandler.ashx?path=/product-images/334.jpg">
    <img height="290" width="267" id="large-image" src="/images/imagehandler.ashx?path=/product-images/334.jpg&amp;width=267&amp;height=290" alt="">
</a>
```

I moved the width and height attributes from your a link (which won't work) to the image element (I also added an alt attribute to make it 100%).

Answer (score -1):

add this css in your style sheet

```
#large-image{ width: 267px; height: 290px}
```

remove height and width from  tag